# Como colocar uma "página" abrindo em um pedaço da página?

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal

No exemplo do [DatePicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/), quando alguém clica no `input` de data, abre o calendário para baixo correto. Como eu posso fazer isso ?

No meu caso eu tenho uma página que só tem um calendário feito por mim, é um calendário específico, mas gostaria de quando alguém clicasse em um botão abrisse um "modal" com o **DatePicker**!

Answer (score 3):

Você pode utilizar o `.show("slow")` e `.hide("slow")` do **jQuery** para exibir e sumir com sua `div`. Segue abaixo um código de exemplo, e aqui o [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1m98c9wy/3/).

HTML:

```
<input id="seuInput" type="text" />
<button id="fechar">fechar</button>

<div class="seuDatePicker"></div>
```

CSS:

```
/*inicialmente a div vem com display: none o que 
deixa ela oculta inicialmente*/
.seuDatePicker {        
    display: none;

    /*atributos utilizados somente para ilustração*/
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;

    /*O position: absolute, evita que se houver conteúdo a 
      baixo da div o mesmo seja jogado para baixo */
    position: absolute;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
/*Pega o evento de inicialização*/
$(document).ready(function () {

    //seto o evento de click no input
    $('#seuInput').click(function () {
        //quando houver um click no input ele exibira sua div
        $('.seuDatePicker').show("slow");
    });

    //seto o evento de click no button
    $('#fechar').click(function(){
        //quando houver um click no input ele sumira com sua div
        $('.seuDatePicker').hide("slow");
    });

});
```

Comment: Ahhhh ótima idéia! Eu sei algumas coisas do Jquery mas não tenho constume de usar! Vou tentar fazer e depois posto aqui o resultado. vlwwww

Comment: beleza.. espero que te ajude :DD

Comment: tem um pequeno problema aqui, se houver conteudo abaixo do input ele será jogado para baixo.

Comment: Bem notado @TobyMosque .. vou adicionar uma melhoria no código acima :D